# Call to a member function has() on a non-object on send mail in swifmailer

Tags: php, symfony

i have created a service

```
services:
app.EmailAndSms:
    class: AppBundle\PublicFunctions\EmailAndSms
    arguments: ["%parameter1%","%parameter2%"]
```

and

```
namespace AppBundle\PublicFunctions;
use Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class EmailAndSms extends Controller{

public function __construct($parameter1,$parameter2) {
  .....
  ....
}

public static function sendEMail() {

$Con=  new Controller;



        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($maildata['sub'])                  
                ->setFrom('notification@xxxxx.com')
                ->setTo($maildata['To'])                       
                ->setReturnPath('notification@xxxxx.com')               ->setBody($Con->renderView(                                          'Emails/EMailTemplate.html.twig', array('content'   => $Passtemplate)), 'text/html');

      }

       }
```

got error
Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object

"file": "/var/www/html/xxxx_rest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php",
            "line": 162,

Comment: What is this for? $Con=  new Controller;

Comment: Can you show the stack trace so we see wich class calls `has()`?

Comment: And more important thing is, controllers and services are different things.

Comment: @Mawcel error in renderView()

Comment: can you avoid to use a static method here? probably is better you move the logic in a service (with the correct dependency of twig and mailer as example) and use where you need

Answer (score 2):

You should start by cleaning up your code.

Remove the static modifier, static methods are to be avoided in general.

You don't need the `new Controller` instance since you already are extending the controller class so instead of

```
$Con->renderView('Emails/EMailTemplate.html.twig', array('content' => $Passtemplate)), 'text/html');
```

Just do

```
$this->renderView('Emails/EMailTemplate.html.twig', array('content' => $Passtemplate)), 'text/html');
```

the non-object `has()` is called on is the service container of your controller because as you instantiate your controller yourself the container is not injected.

In the end you don't need to exten `Controller` either, you should just get the twig service since this is what you need and not the whole service container.

To fix all this inject twig in your service as well as swiftmailer to send your email:

```
 services:
    app.EmailAndSms:
        class: AppBundle\PublicFunctions\EmailAndSms
       arguments: ["%parameter1%","%parameter2%", '@twig', @mailer]
```

Then in your class:

```
namespace AppBundle\PublicFunctions;

class EmailAndSms {

  private $twig;
  private $mailer;

  public function __construct($parameter1,$parameter2, \Twig_environment $twig, $mailer) {
    .....
    ....
    $this->twig = $twig;
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
  }

  public function sendEMail($maildata) { 

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($maildata['sub'])                  
                ->setFrom('notification@xxxxx.com')
                ->setTo($maildata['To'])                       
                ->setReturnPath('notification@xxxxx.com')
                ->setBody($this->twig->render('Emails/EMailTemplate.html.twig', array('content'   => $Passtemplate)));

        $success = $this->mailer->send($message);

        return $success;
   }

}
```

Now to use this service from a controller :

`$this->get('app.EmailAndSms')->sendEmail($maildata);`

Comment: shows error : Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 7 passed to AppBundle\\PublicFunctions\\EmailAndSms::__construct() must be an instance of AppBundle\\PublicFunctions\\Twig_environment, instance of Twig_Environment given, called in /var/www/html/xxxx_rest/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 483 and defined

Comment: My bad it's `\Twig_environment` and not `Twig_environment`

Comment: yes ..$mailData is argument

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
is this correct?